# JSFiddle not downloading online images

Tags: image, jsfiddle

I am trying to download a dog image from an online source and insert it in the navigation logo.

The image link is - http://postimg.org/image/46j7vuv49/

And the JSFiddle link with no image is, http://jsfiddle.net/9zLj60bg/

```
<img src="http://postimg.org/image/46j7vuv49/17316766/" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
```

Why isn't the dog image shown inside the header, when I run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the correct (direct) src path:
http://s12.postimg.org/5lkskkw7h/dog.png

An updated example:
http://jsfiddle.net/9zLj60bg/1/

```
<img src="http://s12.postimg.org/5lkskkw7h/dog.png" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
```

instead of

```
<img src="http://postimg.org/image/46j7vuv49/17316766/" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
```

Comment: The easiest way is to use right click and select `Copy image URL` or check the source code. https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/118238?hl=en